# Maria DB SQL Code and Stored Procedure giving different Output

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

`SQL` Code is mentioned here , please have a look at this.

```
SELECT  concat('{"workbenchStatsByUser": [', GROUP_CONCAT(js SEPARATOR ','))
FROM
(
  SELECT json_object('username', workbenchStatsByUser, 'workbenchStatsByStatus',
         JSON_ARRAY(GROUP_CONCAT( json_object( 'status', TempStatus, 'count', IFNULL(count, 0) ) SEPARATOR ','))) AS Js
  FROM
  (
     SELECT 
        CASE WHEN username IS NULL THEN 'Not Assigned' 
             ELSE CONCAT(username,' - ', rolename) 
        END AS workbenchStatsByUser,
        TempStatus,
        COUNT(TempStatus) AS count  
     FROM users u
     INNER JOIN tempOrgId t ON u.OrgId = t.OrgId
     CROSS JOIN TempStatus ts 
     LEFT JOIN roles r ON r.id = u.roleid
     LEFT JOIN vtask vt ON u.username = vt.updatedby AND ts.TempStatus = vt.status
     GROUP BY workbenchStatsByUser, TempStatus
   ) A
   GROUP BY workbenchStatsByUser
 ) B;
```

Username is null even-though their is a proper value.

Comment: rolename is null?

Comment: Roll name is not null. Same code works fine as SQL Script. But inside SP its not working.

Comment: Are you saying you are getting "Not Assigned"?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
CASE WHEN username IS NULL THEN 'Not Assigned' 
     ELSE CONCAT(username,' - ', rolename) 
END AS workbenchStatsByUser,
```

to

```
COALESCE(CONCAT(username,' - ', rolename), 'Not Assigned') AS workbenchStatsByUser,
```

Comment: Tried, But no luck. Issue happens after grouping. Same code works fine as SQL Script. But inside SP its not working.

Comment: @TIJOJOSEPH -- just repeating that over and over is not helpful.  Please consider trying to solve the problem.  Can you post the code for the SP please.

Comment: Same code is used in side SP. SELECT 
        CASE WHEN username IS NULL THEN 'Not Assigned' 
             ELSE CONCAT(username,' - ', rolename) 
        END AS workbenchStatsByUser,
        TempStatus,
        COUNT(TempStatus) AS count  
     FROM users u
     INNER JOIN tempOrgId t ON u.OrgId = t.OrgId
     CROSS JOIN TempStatus ts 
     LEFT JOIN roles r ON r.id = u.roleid
     LEFT JOIN vtask vt ON u.username = vt.updatedby AND ts.TempStatus = vt.status
     GROUP BY workbenchStatsByUser, TempStatus        Upto this code, it works fine, it will give count with name and status.

Comment: I did not ask what code was used in the SP, I asked you to post the code for the SP.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: I am asking for the source code for the stored procedure.  If as you say is rtrue when you run this code it works but when you run from the stored procedure it does not then the problem must be in the stored procedure, you have not shown us the code to the stored procedure.  I want to help you.  In order to help you I have to look at where the problem is.  So I want you to post the code to the stored procedure.  That is  why I asked you to post the code to the stored procedure.  It has to be more than just the query -- you have to declare the name of the stored procedure, the parameters etc.

Comment: SP is big. Not able to paste it here. Plz share your mail id.